# how can i used RewriteRule ^example.html?site=(.*)$ /example.php?allowfrom=$1 [L] in my htacces file

Tags: .htaccess

I just wanna ask about can i use "?" in my htaccess url rewrite?'

it like this subject title:

```
RewriteRule ^example.html?site=(.*)$ /example.php?allowfrom=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^example.html?id=([0-9]+)&view=([a-z]*)$ /example.php?id=$1&plus=$2 [L]
```

Can I? Special thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Did it work, or not?

Comment: You should escape the `.` in your filename: `example\.html`.  And likewise the `?`.  So you should have `^example\.html\?site=(.*)$  /example.php?allowfrom=$1`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not working. I tried this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use `?` in a `RewriteRule` directive to match the **query string**. `RewriteRule` matches against the URL-path *only*, which does not include the query string. (Aside: Only if the `?` was part of the URL-path, ie. %-encoded in the requested URL, could you match with `RewriteRule` - but that is very unusual and highly discouraged as it will cause confusion and simply break on some systems.)

In order to match the query string, you need to use the `RewriteCond` directive. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^example\.html$ /example.php?allowfrom=%1 [L]
```

Note that `%1` (as opposed to `$1`) matches the parenthesised subpattern in the (last matched) `RewriteCond` directive.